# Foundation 5 project setup with SASS

Tags: css, ruby, git, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm pretty new to the whole world of Compass and SASS, so I might be missing something fundamental here. I'm running into a structuring problem with Foundation 5.

How does one get this all to work neatly within an existing (git) project?
When I run `foundation new myproject`, it clones the basics into 'myproject': a bower_components/ folder for the dependencies, a config.rb in the root, an 'scss' folder where I can modify the SASS files with `compass watch` running in the background to generate my CSS files, and an example index.html file. On its own, I think I get how it all works.

I have an existing project in which I intend to use Foundation 5. My first instinct was to try to "initialize" Foundation in the root of my project: `foundation new .`
Since it's using git, of course it complained the dir wasn't empty. Fair enough, so I made it a sub-folder within my public_html: `foundation new foundation`. I placed config.rb in the root of my project and updated the paths, so I can just run `compass watch` from my root. All this worked pretty neatly, I played around with the scss files and watched my css file get updated accordingly. Then I committed the result and pulled it from a different location. 'foundation', being a repo inside of a repo, didn't get committed along with everything else. Most of the stuff inside there doesn't matter - `foundation new whatever` loads it all up again, and .gitignoring /bower_components is sensible. But the custom code inside the 'scss' directory I do need. I tried setting up my project in a different way, having the 'scss' dir outside of the bower directory, and setting it as the sass_dir in config.rb.
That setup makes sense to me, but I can't get it to work: running `compass watch` fails:

```
     File to import not found or unreadable: foundation.
```

My config.rb right now:

```
    http_path = "/"
    css_dir = "public_html/assets/css"
    sass_dir = "foundation/scss"
    images_dir = "public_html/assets/img"
    javascripts_dir = "public_html/assets/js"
```

How do I tell it explicitly where foundation is? I've tried playing around with 'add_import_path' in config.rb, but that didn't do much.

I have the feeling I'm missing something fundamental here, or maybe I'm overthinking it. Google isn't helping much since Foundation 5 is pretty much fresh out of the oven. Can somebody give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I ended up [downloading foundation-compass-template](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-compass-template) instead of using the foundation command line

Unzipping it into the root of my project and then

```
bower install
```

Here is the [`config.rb`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-compass-template/blob/master/config.rb) that came along with it:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

I know it's not a direct answer but hopefully that project gives you a some direction

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer turned out to be part of the solution. It worked, and looking at the config.rb again I realized the right way to tell Compass where to look for Foundation. D'oh.

My structure is now as follows:

```
config.rb
public_html/
--assets/
----scss/
----css/
----foundation/
------bower_components/
--------foundation/ 
----------scss/ # this is the dir that needed to be imported from config.rb
```

Config.rb:

```
add_import_path "public_html/assets/foundation/bower_components/foundation/scss" # *magic*
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public_html/assets/css"
sass_dir = "public_html/assets/scss"
images_dir = "public_html/assets/img"
javascripts_dir = "public_html/assets/foundation/js"
```

As you can see, this way things are exactly like what I was hoping to get: Foundation's stuff inside of `public_html/assets/foundation` - don't need to touch that directory for anything except running `bower update` from time to time - and my custom scss resides in `public_html/assets/scss`.

Thanks for giving me that much-needed push!

Comment: That's awesome man, Foundation 5 is pretty awesome too, good luck with everything

Comment: I get the same error and have a slightly different project setup. Can you explain where your custom scss file is? And what about the img folder which isn't there in the standard download?